# How to wait for wifi connection (Acces Point) in android (java) in a asynch task programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I am making a android app with android studio. 
The idea is to connect to my device (a access point) with wifi, I don't need to scan mayby in the future, I just wanted to connect with it programmaticly.
And **it does!!! work!!** 
But I wanted to execute some code when the acces point **isn't** available and also the important part of this is that I wanted to execute some code when my android phone **IS** connected to the access point.

**Question:** How can I check whether the state of the wifi is changed in a asynch task?

**This is the code that I used:**

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings,
                container, false);

        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_device_button);

        WifiTask wifiTask = new WifiTask();
        wifiTask.execute();

        return view;
    }

    public class WifiTask extends AsyncTask<Boolean,Void,Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean wifi_enabled) {
            super.onPostExecute(wifi_enabled);


            if(wifi_enabled != true){
                button.setEnabled(false);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Enabling Wifi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if( wifi_enabled == true) {
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Boolean... booleans) {
            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            Boolean is_wifi_enabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
            Log.i("debug", is_wifi_enabled.toString() + " wifi is enabled");

            if(is_wifi_enabled == false)
            {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                is_wifi_enabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();
            }

            return is_wifi_enabled;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aright thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your internet connection
2. if your internet connection is connected do something, is not connected make delay a few minute, if the delay is finished,re check again

for check internet >>>>

```
    private boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    //enter code here
    return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
}
```

for delay>>>

```
handler = new Handler();

final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        tv.append("Hello World");
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is the access point doesn't have a internet connection. It's a esp8266 nodemcu board, running in access point mode. Will it still work?

Comment: I understand the handler but I can't check for internet right? Because I it's a access point without internet connection. Or does this still work?

Comment: simply, using instance to save your action to connected.
check in oncreate or onresume when your instance is not null, if your instance is not null running your runnable to connected wifi

Answer (score 0):

You can register a BroadcastReceiver to be notified when a WiFi connection is changed. if you want then i can give you code sample?

Comment: Brodvastreceiver call automatically when wifi connection is established or disconnect